# Getting the error : ImportError: cannot import name 'to_const'

Tags: django, graphene-django

getting the following import error in my Django(graphene) application, is there a workaround ?

```
from graphene.utils.str_converters import to_camel_case, to_const
ImportError: cannot import name 'to_const'
```

Answer (score 1):

**Error : ?** the above error results from package upgrade, that causes mismatches in dependencies

**Solution : ?** To clear the error above i downgraded the following packages to the versions shown below:

```
aniso8601==7.0.0 
graphene==2.1.8
graphql-core==2.3.2
graphql-relay==2.0.1
```

and the error cleared.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like `to_const` does not exist in the module `str_converters`. Which is why you are getting this error.

Source: https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/blob/master/graphene/utils/str_converters.py

Comment: yea, figured that out  versions of graphene 3.0.0 and above to_const class has been removed from the str_convertes module, Thanks.